# transfer to a different url from xmlhttprequest post call

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am having a xmlhttprequest method like this which gets data authenticated from google sign-in successfully and after that I need to post the data to the login view. Using python and django on the server side.

```
    <form name="Login" method="POST" id="loginForm" action="/login">

function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:

        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); 
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());


        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
        alert("Token*"+id_token); //this gets executed
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        alert(this.responseText);
            }
        };

        xhr.open('POST', '/login');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", '{{ csrf_token }}');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
        alert("*******Token*"+id_token)
  

    try
        {
        xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token); 

                }
    catch (e)
        {
            alert("*"+e.toString)
        console.log('send() error: ' + e.toString());
        return false;
        }
```

views.py

in the views i have defined a login method()

```
def login(request):
  if request.method=='POST':
     #process the request and send the data to another page with some additonal parameters
       role=user_role          
       email=user_email
       fullname=user_name
       return render(request, 'ba/dashboard.html',    {'role':role,'email':email,'fullname':fullname})
```

After the post request is completed the page does not get transferred to the dashboard.html page, it stays on the same login page only.  I want it to be transferred to the dashboard.html page with the parameters given.

This is the console output no **GET** request passed after post is completed

```
[09/Feb/2021 15:53:05] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 4742
```

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for transferring to the different url i had to add this single line

```
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        alert(this.responseText);
        **window.location.href="/home"**  //I had hoped is there any other way to achieve without using this
            }
```

for passing the parameters i did this from the post method and got in the onreadystatechange as shown above:

```
return HttpResponse(
          json.dumps({'role':user_role,'email':user_email,'fullname':user_name})
        
      )
```